# Finding out two such elements out of an unsorted array which have minimum difference without sorting the array

Tags: java, c, data-structures, array-algorithms

We have been given an array of integer :

```
45, 10, 56, 42, 95, 78.
```

We have to find the two elements which have the minimum difference.
I did that in linear time complexity but it works only on the sorted order which altogether leads the running time in quadratic complexity. Do we have any approach where we can do it in logarithmic or linear time complexity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can sort in better than quadratic time

Comment: Yes John, You are absolutely right. But the point is; Is there any other way to where we can find out those elements without sorting using any specific data structure such as Binary search tree. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I can't imagine that there is anything better than O(n * log n) -- which is what you would get with a good sort algorithm, but there probably is a way to tweak a sort algorithm so that it computes what you are looking for while sorting.

Comment: Since these are integers, you can simply sort them in linear time with a counting-sort.

Comment: Counting sort isn't linear in the number of integers but also depends on the size of those integers. It is O(n+k) where k is a bound on the max size. Unless the numbers are e.g. all in 1-100 this wouldn't be very practical.

Comment: You can’t do it in logarithmic time, since you have to at least read every element.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem: "In the computational model which assumes that the floor function is computable in constant time the problem can be solved in O(n log log n) time". We are only considering points in one dimension, and don't need floor for integers, so this seems to suggest `O(n log log n)` is possible (?).

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the array with Heapsort which always is in `O( n * log n)`.
After that you apply your algorithm which is, as you told, in `O(n)`. So you will have `n + n * log n` which is still in `O(n * log n)`

Comment: OP wants better without sorting, hence a -1

Comment: @shekharsuman OP didn't specify wanting to do it without sorting but instead wanted to know if it could be done in better than quadratic time. Given the way that OP phrased the question, it gave the impression that they might have been unaware of sorting algorithms which are asymptotically better than quick sort. Thus, I don't see how this answer deserves a down-vote.

Comment: @JohnColeman Please read this line in OP's question --- *Do we have any approach where we can do it in logarithmic or linear time complexity?*, so we obviously can't go for sorting the given array. **It's not only about being better than quadratic complexity.**

Comment: @JohnColeman- I know only this that OP's last line, which obviously reflects the only question OP is asking is *Do we have any approach where we can do it in logarithmic or linear time complexity?* SO, this heapsort doesn't qualify to come in as an answer here...

Comment: @JohnColeman- I don't want to argue further with you as both of us are wasting energy & time doing futile discussion, better leave it for OP and the rest of the community to decide what to do with this answer... Also, OP responded to your 1st comment as *Yes John, You are absolutely right. But the point is; Is there any other way to where we can find out those elements without sorting using any specific data structure such as Binary search tree. Please enlighten me.*. I don't know what to say further. :(

Comment: @JohnColeman-Sorry to confess,but, I didn't edit that. Seems like a moderator in action there. But, my intention wasn't the same. Sorry again for criticising you that way. I hope you'd forgive my words.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank's for your support. I was also referencing on the last line asking on how to do it in non-quadratic time.

Answer (score -1):

`bool checkPair(int A[], int n, int K)
{
Take Hash Table H of size O(n)
for (i = 0 to n-1)

```
  { 
  int x = K - A[i]
  if (H.search(x) is true) 
      return 1
  H.insert(A[i])
```

}
return -1
} `